# title and displayName properties on CSSearchableItemAttributeSet

Tags: ios, corespotlight, ios-searchapi

I'm building an app that uses `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` with `NSUserActivity` in order to add items to the Spotlight Search index. The items I'm indexing are emojis, which consist of the emoji character itself, a description, and an image that shows the emoji.

I've noticed there is a `title` property on `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` and there's also one called `displayName`. What's the difference between these, where do they appear to the end user, does `title` appear unless `displayName` is provided, or how do these two interact and present themselves to the user? I'm trying to figure out which I need to use in my scenario or if I need both.

The documentation for `displayName` reads: A localized string that contains the name of the item, suitable to display in the user interface.

The documentation for `title` reads: An item title might be the title of a document or MP3 file or the subject of an email message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` displayName property is set, it takes precedence over title property in search results.

If both `displayName` and `title` property of `CSSearchableItemAttributeSet` are set, then the search results will show the `displayName` property. Also, the item is searchable through both title and displayName.

Comment: This is right. I think displayName is something that is for all types of items. But title are specific to some, e.g. document.